# How to call JavaScript function in "php" inputbox in echo on "onChange" event

Tags: php, javascript, html

javascript function which is used in OnChange event

```
function calc(A,B,SUM) { 
    var one = Number(A); 
    if (isNaN(one)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+A); one=0; } 
    var two = Number(document.getElementById(B).value);  
    if (isNaN(two)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+B); two=0; } 
    document.getElementById(SUM).value = parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);
}
```

I have forloop for create 10 input fox

### Input boxes

```
<?php
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
{
    echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsizeqty' name=\"qty[]\" value=\"$qty\" id         ='op1' onChange=\"calc('this.value','op2','result');\"/>";
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

### Input boxes

```
<?php
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
{
    echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' name=\"rate[]\" value=\"$rate\" id      ='op2' onChange=\"calc('this.value','op2','result');\" />";
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>


<?php
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
{
    echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' name=\"sum[]\" value=\"\"     id='result'/>";
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

It's doesn't work here what I am doing.
I'm New in PHP.
Thanks

Comment: try it without `this.value` in parenthesis so remove these: `'`

Comment: what happens if you try this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try and why do you give the quotes in this.value.

```
<?php
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
{
echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsizeqty' name=\"qty[]\" value=\"$qty\" id         ='op1' onChange=\"calc(this.value,'op2','result');\"/>";
echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: and the sun is not correct like example 5 + 5 = 55 >i dont know how to deal with it. Can you help plz.

Comment: document.getElementById(SUM).value = parseInt(one) + parseInt(two); --change javascript final line like this .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145121/how-can-i-use-input-box-id-from-php-to-javascript