# How can I use input Box ID from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

My JavaScript function works fine, but I have problems getting different ids from the PHP input box.

### JavaScript

```
window.onload = function()
{   
new JsDatePick({
useMode:2,
target:"inputField1", //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PASS DIFFERENT ID ex. "inputField1"+ "i"
dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
yearsRange:[1978,2120],
limitToToday:false,
cellColorScheme:"beige",
imgPath:"main/img/",
weekStartDay:1
});
```

### My PHP input box for loop

```
<div class = "start_date" >
<strong><label for="start_date">Start Date</label></strong>
<br/><br/> 
<?php
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
{
echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' id= \"inputField1\"   name=\"start_date[]\" value=\"$start_date\" />";
echo "<br/>";
 }
?>
</div>
```

It works fine, but I would like to have different ID names to use in the JavaScript function. Any ideas?

This doesn't work...

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' id= \"inputField+$k\" name=\"start_date[]\" value=\"$start_date\" />";
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to put the `+` sign to concatenate string within double quotes (it's dot, by the way). What exactly doesn't work in the second code sample?

Comment: I have multiple input box but the date function is works for only 1 input box because of the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely with `JsDatePick` widget. Its `target` parameter takes a single ID of an element, therefore you'd have to wrap the JS code in a loop and initiate a separate instance of the widget for each field ID.

Assuming your input field indexing starts with 1:

```
window.onload = function()
{   
    var i = <?=$totalNumberOfInputs;?>

    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {  
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField" + j, //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PASS DIFFERENT ID ex. "inputField1" + j
            dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
            yearsRange:[1978,2120],
            limitToToday:false,
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            imgPath:"main/img/",
            weekStartDay:1
        });
    }
}
```

You don't need to put the + sign to concatenate strings within double quotes (it's dot, by the way).

Comment: this is the answer for his other question to be precise. there is an error in the code btw. you wanna fix that up.

Comment: While not explicitly stating it, author is trying to enable a date picker on multiple input fields. He had a surplus sign in his `input` field definition AND an `onLoad` code to be fixed. At least that's my understanding, judging from both this and his next question. Perhaps the question should be rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
id= \"inputField+$k\" name=...
```

To:

```
id=\"inputfield$k\" name=...
```

What is screwing it up is the "+" sign.  PHP uses "." to concatenate strings.  `ECHO` out `$k` properly and you shouldn't have any trouble

Comment: Why did you accept this one as an answer, while it doesn't fix your code at all?

Comment: @bth you missed the question. the main question was `It works fine, but I would like to have different ID names to use in the JavaScript function`

Comment: @itachi, not really, given his next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145639/how-can-i-use-for-loop-to-create-different-id-name#comment17881012_13145639

Comment: @bth that's a javascript's question. Nothing related with this question.

Comment: @bth I guess I don't see how what I posted "doesn't fix the code at all".  I posted a solution to what I thought the end result should be and it appears to be an obvious solution.

Comment: @burmat, didn't mean to offend you. While not explicitly stating it, author is trying to enable a date picker on multiple input fields. He had a surplus sign in his input field definition AND an onLoad code to be fixed. At least that's my understanding, judging from both this and his next question.

Comment: @user1778175 Oh I see, you moved your answer away from me to select the answer for another question you asked somewhere else. Makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

```
 //this is doesn't work 
echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' id= \"inputField$k\" name=\"start_date[]\" value=\"$start_date\" />";
```

just remove that `+` sign.

Comment: thanks 1 more question How can i use for loop in JavaScript for increment ID

Comment: javascript has a `for` loop too. identical syntax as that of php.