# How can I use For loop to create different ID name.?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function()
{   
new JsDatePick({
useMode:2,
target:"inputField1", //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PASS DIFFERENT ID ex. "inputField1"+ "i"
dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
yearsRange:[1978,2120],
limitToToday:false,
cellColorScheme:"beige",
imgPath:"main/img/",
weekStartDay:1
});
};
```

In target replace of inputField1 i would like to have inputField1,inputField2,inputField3 etc..

Comment: Because this question is a collateral damage from his previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145121/how-can-i-use-input-box-id-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Do you want to generate multiple javascript functions with different target through PHP `for` cycle?

Comment: Unclear question.. For what? For $i < 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function()
{   
var i = <?=$totalNumberOfInputs;?>

for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {  
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField" + j, //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO PASS DIFFERENT ID ex. "inputField1" + j
        dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
        yearsRange:[1978,2120],
        limitToToday:false,
        cellColorScheme:"beige",
        imgPath:"main/img/",
        weekStartDay:1
    });
}
```

}

This is the answer from my another question Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    temp = "inputField"+i;
    window.onload = function() {   
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode: 2,
            target: temp,
            dateFormat: "%Y-%M-%d",
            yearsRange: [1978,2120],
            limitToToday: false,
            cellColorScheme: "beige",
            imgPath: "main/img/",
            weekStartDay: 1
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: It's work but only for the 4th Number Inputbox

Comment: calender appears in No4 inputbox only. why.?

Comment: Because this answer is wrong - window.onload can only have one function assigned so it'll be the last in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

use a class for the input field like class="inputfield" and using loop to create the html then in javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery_urdu_editor/jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsdatepick-calendar/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
 window.onload = function()
    {   
      $('.inputfield').each(function() {
         var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            //document.write(thisId.'<br />');
         new JsDatePick({
             useMode:2,
             target:thisId,    // putting the id of this element.                    
             dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d",
             yearsRange:[1978,2120],
             limitToToday:false,
             cellColorScheme:"beige",
             imgPath:"main/img/",
             weekStartDay:1
        });
    });
   };
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
        echo '<input type="text" name="textfield'.$i.'" class="inputfield" id="textfield'.$i.'" value="" ><br />';

    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In javascript code we are getting the id's of the elements with its class, Then put that ID in the Calender code. So it is applied for any number of input fields which has that class.
Hope it may help you.